# How to update each and every NULL value in a column to zero?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, sqlite

I have a sqlite3 database. It has some **NULL** values in some columns.
What I want is to loop through each column and update **NULL** value to **0**?
I can do it using pandas, but I wanted to know that if it is possible to do this using sqlite3.
If possible, then do the same command will work in MySQL.?

**CODE :**

```
import sqlite3 as sql

#connect to database
connection = sql.connect("ADARSH.db")

#make a cursor which will move in the database
cursor = connection.cursor()

#execute the different command
def execute(cursor, command):
    return cursor.execute(command)

#print the result
def print_result(result):
    for var in result:
        print(var)

# select every column name
command = """select * from emplyee where 1=0"""
result = execute(cursor, command)

# and store it in a list
col_list = [d[0] for d in result]

#for every column name, replace NULL value with 0
def update_null(cursor, col_list):
    for each_col in col_list:
        command = "update emplyee set {col_name}='0' where {col_name} is null".format(
                    col_name=each_col)
        execute(cursor, command)

update_null(cursor, col_list)
command = """select * from emplyee """
result = execute(cursor, command)
print_result(result)
```

---

This code is not changing anything in my database and it works w/o any error.

Comment: What is that `1=0` stuff doing in there? That's never true.

Comment: Yes it collects every column name through my database.

Comment: That's a really odd way of getting that list. I'm also not sure you can just arbitrarily zero out everything like that. Why not just set the default value to `0` for those columns and disallow `NULL`?

Comment: It works though, problem is once i got columns in a list, i looped through each column and updates it with 0, but somehow it won't work. I can disallow NULL values but just suppose it is provided to me by someone. Think it in data preproceesing way

Comment: If it doesn't work either you're not emitting the right command, or there's errors you're not seeing. I think this code is rather odd in that it makes use of a cursor, too. That could be the source of the problems.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to commit and close the cursor you opened for the changes to be seen in the DB.Add

```
connection.commit()
cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

At the end and check if the changes are reflected in the database.

Comment: Nope, it didn't work. Also, it's not about committing the changes in the database, it is changing database temporarily, and then use it for your particular purpose. Who knows what consequences it may bring if we change the database.

Comment: Are you sure you are getting the names in the col_list? check by inserting a print statement right after creating the col_list

Comment: And select * from emplyee doesn't give you the column names but the Value in the column for each row so you can't use it in the update statement.

Comment: Thanks! As I have mentioned problem is not in col-list , I have used it many times, i can post the link if you have doubt about that. After select* there 1=0 thing that gets me column name